# Flink. Event time. Window processing done too late

Tags: apache-flink

The following code receives messages on a socket, count them by a window of 1min sliding 10s, and zips the input with the cached count.

The processing is event time. The message I receive contains the timestamp I want to use for the processing.

This is close to the training exercise: https://training.ververica.com/exercises/eventTimeJoin.html

```java
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
    env.setParallelism(1);

    // Input
    SocketTextStreamFunction source = new SocketTextStreamFunction("localhost", 9092, "\n", 0);
    SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, Long>> input = env.addSource(source)
        .map(x -> {
            // Eg: 123;2019-11-29T16:03:44+01:00
            String[] split = x.split(";");
            LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(split[1], DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
            long timestamp = ldt.atZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
            return new Tuple2<>(split[0], timestamp);
          });
    // Assign timestamp
    input = input.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
        new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<Tuple2<String, Long>>(Time.milliseconds(100)) {
          @Override
          public long extractTimestamp(Tuple2<String, Long> element) {
            return element.f1;
          }
        });
    input.print("Received");

    // Count the nb of input in the last minutes, sliding by 10s
    SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, Integer>> count = input
        .map(x -> new Tuple2<>(x.f0, 1))
        .keyBy(0)
        .timeWindow(Time.minutes(1), Time.seconds(10))
        .sum(1);
    count.print("Count");

    // Connect the input and the count
    SingleOutputStreamOperator inputWithCount = input
        .keyBy(0)
        .connect(count.keyBy(0))
        .process(
            new CoProcessFunction<Tuple2<String, Long>, Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple3<String, Long, Integer>>() {
              private ValueState<Integer> countCache;

              @Override
              public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
                ValueStateDescriptor<Integer> desc = new ValueStateDescriptor<>("count", Integer.class);
                countCache = getRuntimeContext().getState(desc);
              }

              @Override
              public void processElement1(Tuple2<String, Long> value, Context ctx, Collector<Tuple3<String, Long, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
                Integer cached = countCache.value();
                if (cached == null) {
                  cached = 0;
                }
                out.collect(new Tuple3<>(value.f0, value.f1, cached));
              }

              @Override
              public void processElement2(Tuple2<String, Integer> value, Context ctx, Collector<Tuple3<String, Long, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
                countCache.update(value.f1);
              }
            });
    inputWithCount.print("Output");

    env.execute("Test");
    // I did not include the import, and I pretty-print the Map function for clarity
```

```sh
# Start server:
ncat -lk --broker 9092
# Check what's received:
nc localhost 9092


# I run the Flink app, and use the following command
echo "123;$(date -Iseconds)" | nc 0.0.0.0 9092 ; \
echo "123;$(date -Iseconds)" | nc 0.0.0.0 9092 ; \
sleep 20s ; \                                              
echo "123;$(date -Iseconds)" | nc 0.0.0.0 9092
```

Now when I send 2 lines, wait 20s and send another one. I would expect the 2 first input get a count value of 0, and the third input get a count of 2.
I am correct for the first expectation, not the second.

```
Received> (123,1575043933000)
Received> (123,1575043933000)
Output> (123,1575043933000,0)
Output> (123,1575043933000,0)
... # 20s later
Received> (123,1575043953000)
Output> (123,1575043953000,0)
Count> (123,2)
Count> (123,2)
```

I would have expected that the count would have been processed before the 3rd element would be outputed.
Did I misunderstand event time? Or did I do something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2):

(Following up on David Anderson's explanation and just providing an alternative solution, please read his post first).

If your example is close to your real data (lots of lags), there is also an option to introduce some kind of idle timeout. That's also the recommended way to deal with empty Kafka partitions for certain use cases.

```
public static class BoundedOutOfOrdernessWithTimeoutTimestampExtractor
        implements AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks<FakeKafkaRecord> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final long maxOutOfOrderness;
    private final long idle;
    private long recordTimestamp;

    BoundedOutOfOrdernessWithTimeoutTimestampExtractor(Time maxOutOfOrderness, Time idle) {
        this.maxOutOfOrderness = maxOutOfOrderness.toMilliseconds();
        this.idle = idle.toMilliseconds();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Watermark getCurrentWatermark() {
        return new Watermark(Math.max(recordTimestamp - maxOutOfOrderness, System.currentTimeMillis() - idle));
    }

    @Override
    public long extractTimestamp(FakeKafkaRecord record, long previousElementTimestamp) {
        return recordTimestamp = record.getTimestamp();
    }
}
```

The timestamp assigner is queried according to your watermark interval.

```
env.getConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(100);
```

If `BoundedOutOfOrdernessWithTimeoutTimestampExtractor` did not receive an event for the `idle` period, it will advance the watermark accordingly. You probably want to set `idle` to your `maxOutOfOrderness` (100 ms).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you haven't done anything to guarantee that the count will have been processed before the 3rd element is emitted -- and in fact, it almost certainly won't be.

The reason for this is that the current watermark cannot advance sufficiently so as to trigger the window until the 3rd event arrives. It doesn't matter than you've waited 20 seconds of real time -- what matters is that there have been no events passing through the timestamp extractor, and thus no basis for advancing the watermark.

Furthermore, a `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor` is a periodic watermark generator that by default only creates new watermarks every 200msec. This means that your 3rd event will most likely be processed by the `CoProcessFunction` before the watermark is generated that triggers the window.

You could get more deterministic watermarking if you switched to a punctuated watermark generator -- but the watermark would still follow the 3rd event, so it still wouldn't produce the results you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks David and Arvid!

What I did not understand until now was that Watermark are generated when an event enters the system (while with Processing Time it's automatic, and follows server clock).
And in any case the source become idle, nothing any more would happen.
It's exactly what's written in the [doc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/event_time.html#idling-sources), but I missed it.

I get the output I was expecting with the following particular case:

```sh
echo "123;$(date -Iseconds)" | nc 0.0.0.0 9092 ; \
echo "123;$(date -Iseconds)" | nc 0.0.0.0 9092 ; \
sleep 20s ; \
echo "456;$(date -Iseconds)" | nc 0.0.0.0 9092 ; \
sleep 1s ; \
echo "123;$(date -Iseconds)" | nc 0.0.0.0 9092
```

```sh
Received> (123,1575640032000)
Received> (123,1575640032000)
Output> (123,1575640032000,0)
Output> (123,1575640032000,0)
... # 20s later
Received> (456,1575640052000)
Output> (456,1575640052000,0)
Count> (123,2)
Count> (123,2)
... # 1s later
Received> (123,1575640053000)
Output> (123,1575640053000,2)
```

I find that a bit counter-intuitive that my output could change depending on if I receive other event or not. In my use-case I expect continuous input, but I would prefer a stable behavior.

With your Watermark function Arvid, I get the behavior I desire, thanks. I'm still not sure if I would be able to replay a batch of input or not with it. I would think so, but I'm still getting my head around Watermark and EventTime.
As it is not a bundle function, it is making me wonder if I am using Flink the wrong way?

For reference, this is the code I ended up with.

```java
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
    env.setParallelism(1);

    // Input
    SocketTextStreamFunction source = new SocketTextStreamFunction("localhost", 9092, "\n", 0);
    SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, Long>> input = env.addSource(source)
      .map(new MapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Long>>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Long> map(String value) throws Exception {
          // Eg: 123;2019-11-29T16:03:44+01:00
          String[] split = value.split(";");
          LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(split[1], DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
          long timestamp = ldt.atZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
          return new Tuple2<>(split[0], timestamp);
        }
      });
    // Assign timestamp
    input = input.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BoundedOutOfOrdernessWithTimeoutTimestampExtractor(Time.milliseconds(10), Time.milliseconds(10)));
    input.print("Received");

    // Count the nb of input in the last minutes, sliding by 10s
    SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, Integer>> count = input
      .map(new MapFunction<Tuple2<String, Long>, Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Integer> map(Tuple2<String, Long> x) throws Exception {
          return new Tuple2<>(x.f0, 1);
        }
      })
      .keyBy(0)
      .timeWindow(Time.minutes(1), Time.seconds(10))
      .sum(1);
    count.print("Count");

    // Connect the input and the count
    SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple3<String, Long, Integer>> inputWithCount = input
      .keyBy(0)
      .connect(count.keyBy(0))
      .process(
        new CoProcessFunction<Tuple2<String, Long>, Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple3<String, Long, Integer>>() {
          private ValueState<Integer> countCache;
          private long previousCountTimestamp;

          @Override
          public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
            ValueStateDescriptor<Integer> desc = new ValueStateDescriptor<>("count", Integer.class);
            countCache = getRuntimeContext().getState(desc);
          }

          @Override
          public void processElement1(Tuple2<String, Long> input, Context ctx,
            Collector<Tuple3<String, Long, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
            Integer cached = countCache.value();
            if (cached == null) {
              cached = 0;
            }
            out.collect(new Tuple3<>(input.f0, input.f1, cached));
          }

          @Override
          public void processElement2(Tuple2<String, Integer> count, Context ctx,
            Collector<Tuple3<String, Long, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
            countCache.update(count.f1);

            ctx.timerService().deleteEventTimeTimer(previousCountTimestamp);
            previousCountTimestamp = ctx.timestamp() + Time.minutes(1).toMilliseconds();
            ctx.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(previousCountTimestamp);
          }

          @Override
          public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext ctx, Collector<Tuple3<String, Long, Integer>> out)
            throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Cache expires");
            countCache.clear();
          }
        });
    inputWithCount.print("Output");

    env.execute("Test");
```

Btw, I had to set a cache expire.

With the output:

```sh
echo "123;$(date -Iseconds)" | nc 0.0.0.0 9092 ; \
echo "123;$(date -Iseconds)" | nc 0.0.0.0 9092 ; \
sleep 20s ; \
echo "456;$(date -Iseconds)" | nc 0.0.0.0 9092 ; \
sleep 1s ; \
echo "123;$(date -Iseconds)" | nc 0.0.0.0 9092
```

```sh
Received> (123,1575641582000)
Received> (123,1575641582000)
Output> (123,1575641582000,0)
Output> (123,1575641582000,0)
... # few s later
Count> (123,2)
... # 10s later
Count> (123,2)
... # few s later
Received> (456,1575641602000)
Output> (456,1575641602000,0)
Received> (123,1575641603000)
Output> (123,1575641603000,2)
... # few s later
Count> (123,3)
Count> (456,1)
... # 10s later
Count> (456,1)
Count> (123,3)
... # 10s later
Count> (456,1)
Count> (123,3)
... # 10s later
Count> (123,3)
Count> (456,1)
...
```